# Условия скидок Bitrix

Tags: битрикс

На сайте стоит условие скидки(Если в корзине свыше 2-ух позиций то применяется скидка 5% ) как сделать так , чтобы из этого условия исключить некоторые разделы?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В настройках скидки укажите для каких разделов не применять.

Comment: @NikolajSarry а где это найти в настройках ? ничего не вижу там , есть только условия

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно настроить условия скидки. Это делается в административной части сайта в меню "Маркетинг"-"Товарный маркетинг" вы можете отредактировать подходящий пункт из списка **Предустановленный список маркетинговых акций** или можете настроить **Правила работы с корзиной**

Где конкретно сейчас вам настроили телепатически сложно сказать. Это места, где это настраивается штатно.

Comment: я скрин прикрепил к вопросу , можешь пожалуйста глянуть , вроде все норм настроил.

Comment: первая акция при добавлении в корзину свыше одного товара применяется скидка 5% , а вот 2ое правило говорит про скидку 0% к определенным разделам . но почему то не работает.

Comment: Добавьте второе правило в первую скидку. Вы можете добавить туда условие и поставить в для разделов "не равно". Тогда правило скидки 5% будет смотреть на количество товара и на раздел сразу. А так у вас наблюдается конфликт правил.